# Launch cljs nREPL connected to lein project template

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, cursive, shadow-cljs

I have created a ClojureScript project using:

`lein new re-frame my-project`

I've then opened it in IntelliJ using Cursive. In the terminal after typing `lein dev`, it prompts me with the message:

```sh
shadow-cljs - HTTP server available at http://localhost:8280
shadow-cljs - server version: 2.8.52 running at http://localhost:9630
shadow-cljs - nREPL server started on port 8777
shadow-cljs - watching build :app
[:app] Configuring build.
[:app] Compiling ...
[:app] Build completed. (203 files, 1 compiled, 0 warnings, 3.65s)
```

I can open the server using the link which directs me to a REPL, but not the nREPL connected to the browser. Following their [documentation](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#cljs-repl) I type `shadow-cljs clj-repl` in to another terminal, which opens a REPL but not one that is connected to my browser or project. If I type `(js/alert "hi m8")` in to the REPL it responds:

```sh
Syntax error compiling at (REPL:2:1).
No such namespace: js
```

My question is, is how do I use the nREPL it says has started and preferably how do I access it in the integrated REPL in IntelliJ?

Thanks.

### Update

Have got it working as below but if anyone knows how to get it working here in Cursive / IntelliJ:

[image]

That would be super.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nREPL connection will always start out in Clojure mode. You can switch it to use CLJS by calling `(shadow.cljs.devtools.api/repl :app)` and return to Clojure mode via `:cljs/quit`.

You should however be connecting to a "Clojure REPL" -> "Remote" and then "localhost" with port `8777`. This is configured as the default in the `re-frame` template via `shadow-cljs.edn` `:nrepl {:port 8777}`.

The screenshot you posted looks like you connected to the random port `lein` created. This will also work but requires additional configuration for the [nREPL middleware](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#_embedded_nrepl_server).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it. You have to use `shadow-cljs cljs-repl app` in another terminal.